NetSuite UserEvent Form.addfield values does not save
need some help.
I am trying to add a custom field (checkbox) inside the Price Level record using form.addfield.  I was able to display the checkbox it but it is not saving the value.
I also tried on afterSubmit and use setValue, however, I am not sure how to pass it on beforeLoad so I can set it on the .defaultValue, which only works on beforeLoad.
ANy possible workaround?
function beforeLoad(scriptContext) {
    let objPriceLevel = scriptContext.newRecord;
    let form = scriptContext.form;

    try {
            let fldSyncBox = form.addField({
                id: "custpage_syncbox",
                label: "Sync",
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.CHECKBOX,
              });        
              let bolPriceSync = objPriceLevel.getValue("custpage_syncbox");
              log.debug("bolPriceSync", bolPriceSync);

              fldSyncBox.defaultValue = bolPriceSync;
    } catch (err) {
      log.error("beforeLoad", err.message || err.name || JSON.stringify(err));
    }
  }


A field added in a beforeLoad user event script is not a field on the record. It's a temporary field that is generally used for some sort of UI enhancement.
If you are persisting something you likely want to create an actual custom field. It can be positioned in the form builder. If you are using the added field to trigger some logic I think you may need to read it in the beforeSubmit user event like a regular field ctx.newRecord.getValue({fieldId:'custpage_syncbox'})

Unfortunately, we cannot add a custom field on Price Level record, that is why we resort to adding a field on beforeLoad. Any possible workaround?

If you want to decorate things like price levels what you can do is create a custom record with a custom list/record field that links to your price level. Then any extra configuration for price levels is stored in the custom record.
